# How to escape PHP's http_build_query?

Tags: php, escaping

[image: Validator errors]

I'm confused how to escape this line of PHP code:

```
<p><a href=/foobar.php?<?php echo http_build_query(array("ic" => "123", "address" => "12 Hill Street", "name" => "John Doe" )); ?>>Testing</a></p>
```

`urlencode` makes validation pass, but $_GET request becomes mashed. `htmlspecialchars` doesn't encode the equals sign. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Quote*** your HTML attribute, HTML-encode the value:

```
<p><a href="/foobar.php?<?php echo htmlspecialchars(http_build_query(...)); ?>">Testing</a></p>
           ^                                                                  ^
```

The parser can't correctly find the end of the attribute value unless you quote it.